# Markdown issue: incorrect list numbering view/preview/edit/edit history

Tags: bug, markdown, editor

I've stumbled across this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14482933/2170171 and wanted to fix numbering (second item shown as "1" instead of "2"):

[image]

Clicking `edit` I see that numbering inside and on preview is "correct" and shows "2" inside body & preview, which is differs from "1" we see:

[image]

The same can be seen in edit history - it looks like previous editors were struggling with it before refused to achieve correct result.

1. This is confusing at least
2. What is markdown fix / workaround for this?
3. Is there a way to see "real" preview somehow without actually saving edit?

Comment: I have Updated the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14482933/revisions).For future reference, if it is a sublist, give an additional space.Here, the list with alphabetical points needed additional space to make it a sublist of the first point i.e. `Server side :`